# Python get __doc__ documentation for instance variable

Tags: python, documentation

In python, I know I'm supposed to document instance variables like this:

```
self.x = 22
"""docstring for x"""

#: docstring for x
self.x = 22
self.x = 22 #: docstring for x
```

But I can't seem to find a way to get hold of that documentation in code. `MyClass.x.__doc__` gives me the doc of the actual type that is in `x`

So the question is: How do I get `"docstring for x"` from `self.x`?

Comment: There are source code parsers for Python that allow you to associate code items by their order in the parsing sequence. While non-trivial, this makes it nevertheless possible to associate preceding documentation lines with any following code construct such as instance variable assignment. I don't know of any tool or library implementing this though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a feature of documentation utilities such as Sphinx and Epydoc, not a standard feature of Python. I don't believe that there is any direct way of getting variable docstrings.

See http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-docstring.html#variable-docstrings

Comment: @Waldo Bronchart: The last line of the variable-docstrings section the link targets appears to be incomplete: "Notice that variable docstrings are only available for documentation when the source code is available for parsing: it is not possible to retrieve variable". If complete it would probably be something like "...it is not possible to retrieve variable docstrings at runtime."

Answer (score 8):

According to [PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), instance variables are supposed to be documented in the docstring of the class:

> The docstring for a class should summarize its behavior and list the public methods and instance variables.

Just writing the docstring after the initialisation of an instance variable won't give you any way to access it.